# Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Function'

Tags: javascript, angular, function, class, typescript

Im tryin to pass the parameter 'this' to a function this way:

```
modalshow = new Confirmation(false, this.changea(this), this.changer);
```

and the Confirmation Class is like this:

```
 constructor(
    public show: boolean,
    public actionAccept: Function,
    public actionReject: Function
  ) {}
```

But i keep getting the error:

> Argument of type 'void' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Function'

So, i don't know what is the problem and what should i do.

Comment: You are passing the **value** returned by calling `this.changea(this)` and the **value**  of `this.changer`. What are they? BTW, "void" is not an [ECMAScript *Type*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument you are passing is `this.changea(this)` - the result of this is that you are passing the return value of te `changea` function, not the function itself.

If you want to pass a function as the argument, and preserve the meaning of `this`, you can use:

```
modalshow = new Confirmation(false, () => this.changea(this), this.changer);
```

You have now wrapped your code in a function, that hasn't yet been executed.